# Invalid .apk file with tensorflow example

Tags: android, android-ndk, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow; I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) and downloaded bazel and NDK based on the tutorial. My machine is windows but I am running Ubuntu on a virtual machine just for the sake of this tutorial. I successfully built the .apk file but when I tried to install it on a device(runs marshmallow) I get "Invalid apk .file" 
This is the resulting .apk file
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you signed the APK?

Comment: No, I have not. It doesn't say that you sign the apk prior to installing in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my path to the apk was wrong. I pointed it to the right path, it works fine now. I know this is stupid and not going to help anyone but Ubuntu seems to throw to store folders and files everywhere and doesn't make much sense, so I was tricked by it.

Comment: Maybe specify what you mean by Ubuntu storing files everywhere, what your path looked like, and what it is now. If you do so that could be a useful answer to someone else with a similar problem. Once you do that, be sure to mark your question as the accepted answer.